# SwiftUI: Stretching Background Images To Fill

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is about filling a background with a color.

I am building a SwiftUI version of [this project](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Spinner/tree/master/RVS_Spinner_Tabbed_Test_Harness). It's a tabbed app (test harness).

[This is my Working Project](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVSSwiftUISpinner)

The first thing that I'm doing, is setting the tabs up. I expect to be learning a lot, and hitting a lot of walls.

The first wall, is that I fill the app background with a (ghastly) virulent green background gradient.

This takes the form of a stripe that I stretch horizontally.

With IB, not an issue.

With SwiftUI, I need to figure it out.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RVS_SpinnerSwiftUI_Tabbed_Test_Harness_ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabbedView(selection: $selection, content: {
            VStack {
                Text("TEST 0")
                    .background(Color.clear)
                }
                .tabItemLabel(Text("Simple Center"))
                .tag(0)
                .background(Image("background-gradient")
                        .scaledToFill()
//                        .scaledToFit()
            )
            VStack {
                Text("TEST 1")
                    .background(Color.clear)
                }
                .tabItemLabel(Text("Bottom Right"))
                .tag(1)
                .background(Color.clear)
            VStack {
                Text("TEST 2")
                    .background(Color.clear)
                }
                .tabItemLabel(Text("Rotator"))
                .tag(2)
            VStack {
                Text("TEST 3")
                    .background(Color.clear)
                }
                .tabItemLabel(Text("Quadrants"))
                .tag(3)
                .background(Color.clear)
        })
        .padding()
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RVS_SpinnerSwiftUI_Tabbed_Test_Harness_ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

The issue is with `.background(Image("background-gradient"))` in the first tab. I am using this to prototype the operation. Once I figure everything out, I'll be making this work more sensibly.

[Here's the file in GH.](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Spinner/blob/SwiftUIDevelopment/RVS_SpinnerSwiftUI_Tabbed_Test_Harness/RVS_SpinnerSwiftUI_Tabbed_Test_Harness_ContentView.swift)

It's likely to change over time, so I understand if people want me to nuke the link, but it does allow folks to see it in place (for now).

I'm interested in figuring out how to stretch the background image horizontally to fill the tab.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "stretch...to fill the tab". You have made this image a background for your text. Therefore I expect it to be the size of the text. Moreover, SwiftUI image views are the size of the underlying image by default. You haven't dictated any other size or made this image `.resizable`.

Comment: Hi Matt. I'm not talking about the text item. I have been moving the background function around. I started off as the background of the tabbed view, but I figured that I might find the answer I'm looking for more quickly if I just concentrate on one of the contained views.

Comment: In IB, you simply add an image view, and stretch it to fill the container (attaching the various anchors). The image will stretch to fill, so this way, you can make a simple stripe fill an entire screen flexibly.

Comment: I need to do the same thing here, and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: I edited the source to illustrate the kinds of things I'm exploring.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the size of the view you're in so that you can set the image's dimensions accordingly?

Comment: No, I'm trying to do the same thing that I do with IB. I just want to declare a simple fill mode, so the image dynamically stretches. Maybe I am approaching it wrong. Since this is a declarative approach, I might be able to assign a method that reads the container size, and stretches the image to fill it, but that seems a bit much. I'd think there should be a way to do this declaratively.

Comment: We're all trying to figure out how things should be done properly. There's always multiple ways to do stuff, but only one is the right way.

Comment: I'm still not understanding. If you want an image that is the width of its container, that is easy. It's making that image the `background` of your text that prevents it. If you don't want that, don't do that.

Comment: It's not the background of the text item. It's the VStack. However, I think that I see what you mean. You mean that I should simply stack in an image in a ZStack, under the items. Let me try that.

Comment: Yeah...I'm encountering weirdness. I know there's bugs in the engine, but I want to believe the problem is mine. If I declare a ZStack, then the Tab Bar doesn't display.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the way the dimensions are being calculated. If I set the TabbedView to scaleToFit(), it ... sort of shows, but in the wrong place. I'll figure this out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And the answer is...

Envelope, please?

`.resizable()`!

You DO use the `.background()` method, but you make the `Image()` resizable, like so:

```
var body: some View {
    TabbedView(selection: $selection, content: {
        VStack {
            Text("TEST 0")
                .background(Color.clear)
            }
            .tabItemLabel(Text("Simple Center"))
            .tag(0)
        VStack {
            Text("TEST 1")
                .background(Color.clear)
            }
            .tabItemLabel(Text("Bottom Right"))
            .tag(1)
            .background(Color.clear)
        VStack {
            Text("TEST 2")
                .background(Color.clear)
            }
            .tabItemLabel(Text("Rotator"))
            .tag(2)
        VStack {
            Text("TEST 3")
                .background(Color.clear)
            }
            .tabItemLabel(Text("Quadrants"))
            .tag(3)
            .background(Color.clear)
    })
    .background(
        Image("background-gradient")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    )
    .padding()
}
```

That will stretch it.

[image]

Now, I need to figure out how to make the TabbedView clear its background.

Comment: I have a feeling that the answer to the TabbedView issue will be to not use a SwiftUI TabbedView, and use a UIKit UITabController instead.

Comment: But I said all of that.  Long ago. You just didn’t listen.

Comment: You are correct. And you are also correct in that I didn't listen (read). I apologize. Make your suggestion an answer, and I will greencheck it.

Comment: Thanks but there's a reason why my comment was a comment: it just seemed so trivially obvious that your code said one thing while your claim about what you wanted to accomplish said something completely different.

Comment: I miss obvious all the time. In this case, it was because I didn't make the (supposedly obvious) connection that an entity needs to be marked mutating, in some way, in order to mutate. In the case of SwiftUI, it is a mix of both. I'll get it. I've only been doing this for a couple of days. And some of the best answers that I get here, are ones that seem trivially obvious. I have absolutely no ego wrapped up in this at all. I become right, often by proposing wrong, and being corrected.

Comment: I appreciate that. We all learn. What I'm suggesting is that this is too trivial an instance of learning to make a good Stack Overflow question. You could at least have watched the WWDC SwiftUI videos. I've never written a line of SwiftUI in my life, but I have watched WWDC 2019 video 237, which covers the matter at hand quite thoroughly. Surely it's reasonable to expect _some_ level of acquaintance with a subject as a minimum before it warrants Stack Overflow bandwidth?

Comment: Will do. I'll watch it. I've often avoided the WWDC videos, because they can be incomprehensible. I feel like I've lost two hours of my life, watching, then re-watching, someone with a thick French accent go over a topic that I learn in five minutes by banging into a guardrail. I tend to learn by driving into the weeds right away. I find out where the potholes are quite quickly. Also, if there is one thing that geeks love doing, it's telling other geeks they are wrong.  It's almost like I'm doing a public service. :)

Comment: So I'll delete this question in a little while.

Comment: OK. Can't delete it. NBD, but y'all will have to live with the "noise." I do appreciate you pointing out that video. I actually found the second section interesting, and it may inform the way I work on the next version of the project. Thanks!

Comment: ...and watch this space. Interesting stuff on the way... I write LOTS of code.

Answer (score 2):

I find a very easy way to put images in my app background. 
It is perfectly stretched and the fill also covers the safe area.
You should try.

[image]

import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Image("imagename")
                .resizable() 
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very simple, indeed!

Comment: But then the content you want on top of this image will ignore the safe area as well :/